# Place multiple variables after another variable

Tags: shell

Trying to have a multiple variable follow another variable, but I'm not getting 7 different VOL variables.

```
NME=(Y6T1 Y6-T1 Y6.T1 Yr6T1 Yr6-T1 Yr6.T1 Yr6Term1)
VOL=/Volumes/${NME}

for Copy in $VOL ; do
    echo $Copy
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `zsh` (since you seem to be using `zsh` syntax), you'd do:

```
nme=(Y6T1 Y6-T1 Y6.T1 Yr6T1 Yr6-T1 Yr6.T1 Yr6Term1)
vol=(/Volumes/$^nme)
for Copy in $vol; do
  printf '%s\n' $Copy
done
```

Without the `^`, `/Volumes/$nme` would be the concatenation of `/Volumes/` with the values of the array so only the first element would have `/Volumes/` prepended to it.

Or, when assigning to a scalar variable instead of an array variable, like you did, it would be `/Volumes/` concatenated with the array elements joined with the first character of `$IFS`.

(note that the behaviour would be different in `ksh` or `bash`, where `$nme` is just short for `${nme[0]}`).

Adding the `^` in `$^nme` allows the concatenation to be *distributed* to each element of the array.

That `^` is reminiscent of `rc`'s `^` (non-)operator and possibly explains the origin of that `^` zsh variable expansion operator. In `rc`:

```
nme=(Y6T1 Y6-T1 Y6.T1 Yr6T1 Yr6-T1 Yr6.T1 Yr6Term1)
vol=(/Volumes/^$nme)
for (Copy in $vol) printf '%s\n' $Copy
```

That `^` is not needed. `vol=(/Volumes/$nme)` would work just the same. The point here is that `rc` does distribute the concatenation. However `^` (which is just ignored and discarded) can be seen as a *concatenation operator* because it facilitates things like `$nme^2` (`$nme2` would be treated as the nme2 variable, you'd need to write it `$'nme'2` otherwise).

In `bash` (also works in `zsh`):

```
nme=(Y6T1 Y6-T1 Y6.T1 Yr6T1 Yr6-T1 Yr6.T1 Yr6Term1)
vol=("${nme[@]/#//Volumes/}")
for Copy in "${vol[@]}"; do
  printf '%s\n' "$Copy"
done
```

Here, we're using the parameter leading pattern substitution operator (`${param/#pattern/replacement}`) applied to each element of the array.
Here, we're replacing the empty string at the start of each element with `/Volumes/`).

While that syntax comes from `ksh93`, it doesn't work in `ksh93` as it doesn't like that empty pattern. There, you need to replace `${nme[@]/#//Volumes/}` above with `${nme[@]/#@()//Volumes/}` for instance. `@()` being an empty group.

Of course, in standard `sh` syntax, you can always do:

```
set Y6T1 Y6-T1 Y6.T1 Yr6T1 Yr6-T1 Yr6.T1 Yr6Term1
for Copy do
  printf '/Volumes/%s\n' "$Copy"
done
```

or:

```
set Y6T1 Y6-T1 Y6.T1 Yr6T1 Yr6-T1 Yr6.T1 Yr6Term1
for Copy do
  Copy=/Volumes/$Copy
  printf '%s\n' "$Copy"
done
```

Or if assuming your `echo` ([you should really get used to using `printf` instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)) was not just a place holder and all you want to do is display those one per line:

```
set Y6T1 Y6-T1 Y6.T1 Yr6T1 Yr6-T1 Yr6.T1 Yr6Term1
printf '/Volumes/%s\n' "$@"
```

Or:

```
printf '/Volumes/%s\n' Y6T1 Y6-T1 Y6.T1 Yr6T1 Yr6-T1 Yr6.T1 Yr6Term1
```

Comment: what does `rc`'s `^` do? i sometimes get tripped up in `zsh` on `^` and never bothered to find out why. the problem usually happens when i screw up my terminal and need `stty sane erase ^H`. also, probably you skipped it because its not really about variables, but it might be the asker just wants `printf /Volumes/%s\\n 1 2 3 4 5`. people sometimes go out of their way to put stuff in variables, i think.

Comment: @mikeserv In `rc`, `^` is more like a non-operator. It's ignored but facilitates `$var^something` which you'd have to be write `$'var'something` otherwise. It's just that in `rc`, `x$array` (or `x^$array`) and `$'array'x` (or `$array^x`), where `array=(a b)`, expand to `xa` `xb` and `ax` `bx` instead of `xa` `b` or `a` `bx`. In `zsh`, `$^array` enables a similar behaviour (it's different for `$a^$b` in rc vs `$^a$^b` in zsh though). In `zsh`, `^` is an extendedglob negation operator. In the Bourne shell, `^` is another name for `|`.